# /root as bind mount?

Tags: debian, mount, root, root-filesystem, bind-mount

I am migrating my system from Debian 32 bit to Debian 64 bit. It is installed on `/dev/sda2`, so I created `/dev/sda3`, installed the new system there, synched installed packages and configuration files from `/etc` and used bind mounts to mount `/data` and `/home` from the old system into the new system. So far so good.

Now before I do the final switch, I want to use the system for some weeks. The only thing that is missing is `/root`, which I rsynched into the new partition. I'd rather have it a bind mount too, but I'm hesitant with this one. So the question:

1. Can `/root` be a bind mount, or are there going to be problems?
2. What happens between system start and the mount operation, could there be problems?

Answer (score 2):

/root is just the home directory of user root.

Usually /root is a rather "uninteresting" directory only used when you login interactively as root. If you don't remember that you have manually edited or created interesting files there then I would not sync it at all.

On the other hand bind mounting /root should not cause any trouble. Maybe there are some (auto-generated) config files which are nice to sync, like .ssh/known_hosts or .ssh/authorized_keys.

In doubt see

```
diff -rq /path/to/old/root /root
```

if you see something you like to keep from the old installation.

Comment: Well I rsynced it to begin with. It's just I want a smooth transition, so since I boot both versions currently it would be great that I don't have to think about rsyncing after a switch. I have some stuff in `/root` (like ssh keys), which maybe is a bad idea to begin with.